# PHP and Derby: Connection Failed

Tags: php, odbc, derby

currently I am working with PHP. And I would like to connect PHP and Derby Database. But, unfortunately, everytime I tried to connect them, I got these warning:

> Warning: odbc_connect(): in D:\Programme\xampp\htdocs\test_derby.php on line 7
>
> Warning: odbc_autocommit() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in D:\Programme\xampp\htdocs\test_derby.php on line 12
>
> Warning: odbc_do() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   in D:\Programme\xampp\htdocs\test_derby.php on line 15
>
> Warning: odbc_result_all() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null
>   given in D:\Programme\xampp\htdocs\test_derby.php on line 16
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function DbDisconn() in
>   D:\Programme\xampp\htdocs\test_derby.php on line 17

Here is My Code:

```
$username = "sysdba";
$password = "masterkey";
$dsn = "Driver=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/gasteparkplatze";

$conn = odbc_connect($dsn,$username,$password);

odbc_autocommit($conn, TRUE);

$que = "select * from gastgeber";
$res = odbc_do($conn, $que);
odbc_result_all($res, "BORDER=1");
```

NB: The username and password is default Derby's default username and password. Correct me if am wrong, because I got that username and password from following link: http://www.sysaid.com/Sysforums/posts/list/7400.page

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a ODBC driver not a JDBC one to use odbc_connect. Easysoft have a ODBC Driver for Derby, they also have a ODBC-JDBC Bridge that would allow what you are doing to work. The ODBC driver is the simpler cleaner solution. [ODBC Driver for Derby](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-derby-driver/index.html)

Comment: i have tried to do so, but I got this error: 
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Easysoft][ODBC-Derby Driver][DRDA]General error: failed to recieve reply to EXCSAT, SQL state HY000 in SQLConnect in D:\Programme\xampp\htdocs\test_derby.php on line 7

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\Programme\xampp\htdocs\test_derby.php on line 7

Comment: A timeout of 30 seconds, followed by an error, makes it sounds like your Derby Network Server is not running. Is the Network Server running when you try your connect?

Comment: Would there be no problem if i ADD another ODBC driver (a 32bit version to cater my 32bit application) to a server with an existing 64bit version (which some other application maybe using the 64bit)? Would it not create confilict to other applications? I am worried that if I install a 32bit version that it may affect the existing and running applications on the server.

Comment: You will need to keep the 32 and 64 bit driver manager and driver libs separate, but other than that there is no problem. You can share the odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files by using the Driver64 option in odbcinst,ini. Look for Driver64 in http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/db2.html